# Using Logentries for logging on Heroku

Tags: heroku, logentries

I have added logentries as an add-on on Heroku.
I then obtained Account key from logentries profile page.

I used this account key in my application as below:

```
/*  services/logger.js */

var Logger = require('le_node');

var logger = new Logger({
  token: '9a7562ac-0fba-41ba-9e02-abcdefghi'   //this is a fake key
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Now in my other files I am using the above as:

```
/* some js file */
var logger = require('../services/logger');

logger.info('Executing Game.creator.js');
```

When I run this script on my local machine, I expect that logging would happen on logentries and then i would see the log details..however that does not seem to be the case.

Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to configure anything when using logentries as an add-on on heroku.

The [heroku logging platform](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) will get all logs sent to STDOUT or STDERR by your app, and make it availbable to a few places.
The most known one being `heroku logs`.

It will also send those logs to any drain URL configured on your app, which logentries can automatically configure when you setup the add-on.
That means as soon as the add-on is configured, all logs sent to STDOUT or STDERR by your app will be received by logentries.